# session value not printed on blade page

Tags: laravel-5

session value not displayed on blade page

**adminController**

```
use Session;
Session::put('adminusername', "test");
echo Session::get('adminusername'); //it prints here fine
```

**mater.blade.php**

```
Welcome:{!! Session::get('adminusername') !!}
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? In the newer versions of Laravel if you are defining your routes outside of `web` middleware group it doesn't initialize the `Session`. Need full `Controller` and `routes.php` code to further analyze.

Comment: laravel version 5.0 ok sir solved error got your point thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the full controller and routes file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to define route in middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::group(array('prefix'=>'admin'),function(){
    Route::get('login', 'admin\AdminHomeController@showLogin');
    Route::post('check', 'admin\AdminHomeController@login_check');

    Route::get('dashboard', 'admin\AdminHomeController@showDashboard');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 use Session;


public function showsession()
 {
   Session::put('adminusername', 'test');
   return View::make("folder/page.php")->with('adminusername',Session::get('adminusername'););
 }
```

View

```
Welcome:{!! $adminusername !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

put this middleware in your kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
       .....other classes
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        ......other classes
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```